.setHelpText throws an error: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setHelpText on object FormApp.Item
This script has been working just fine and suddenly produces an error. Here is the script that I have modified so it will run even though it generates an error:
function addEdplanUrl() {
  const form = FormApp.openByUrl('MY FORM ID');

  try {
    const month = form.getItems()[0];
    // Set the description of the first item
    month.setHelpText("Please click on the month for which you are submitting samples");
   } catch (e) {
    // Log the error without stopping the script
    Logger.log("Error setting help text: " + e.message);
  }
}

Here is the error:

Info   Error setting help text: Unexpected error while getting the method or property setHelpText on object FormApp.Item

The issue is that even though the script generates an error it actually does set the help text as expected. But in the use case I am using it, the script needs to continue running, because it calls other scripts like this to add help text to other items. When it encounters the error it stops the script. This script I am sharing is modified with the try/catch so it does complete, but this will entail me fixing multiple instances of this script that are deployed.
Has anyone else had an issue with setHelpText suddenly generating this error?
As noted above I added the try/catch part of this script which does make it work, but I am concerned about why it is generating an error. It worked fine until just a few weeks ago.

I have no explanation to offer, but if no solution is found and the problem persists - it could be some sort of server issue -, you could always continue executing the rest of the script in the catch block, after verifying that the thrown error is indeed that one.

It appears that your case has similar issues, and you’ve already posted it in the issue tracker. Here’s the link to the created case, which will help other community members easily track any updates.

It is a known issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/371004125

I'm sure this is unintended but in FormApp.openByUrl('MY FORM ID'); the Form URL and the Form Id are NOT interechangeable.

The question doesn't describe the "type" of item; but let's assume that is "Multiple choice". So try month.asMultipleChoiceItem().setHelpText("Please click on the month for which you are submitting samples");

I do accept that the script is displaying an error message; but have you also found that the script, as written, is also updating the Help text?

@Tedinoz Yes, that is a typo, it is the form URL that I am using. I have tried it by identifying the type of item and it still throws the error. And yes it is actually updating the form even though it is creating an error, which is why it seems to be a bug that started a week or so ago, Had been working hundreds of times prior to last week, The issue for me is that there are many scripts following this, so the error stopped the script. I have fixed it so far by using try/catch and logging the error, so at least the script continues.

Suggest you read Why does my form script error out after correctly setting Title? (dated yesterday). This is an "almost" identical problem that appears to have resolved itself; I'm wondering whether your problem also resolved itself.
